# Compare between sheets in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm new to VBA and currently busting my head to maintain item list in excel which is connected to database.

- sheet1 columns (starts from column B)

  UID   |  itemno.  |  itemweight  |  processed
- sheet2 same headers(starts from column A)

  UID   |  itemno.  |  itemweight  |  deleted

I framed this theoretical target and coded it, tried several times.

It is not looping :( and not achieving my target.

Any suggestions will be helpful! Thanks in advance

Following are my steps framed with the code:

```css
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()


' Loop until no new UID found
' 1. GoTo Sheet2 to First/Next Cell with UID
' 2. Read UID value
' 3. GoTo Sheet1
' 4. Search in UID column for read UID
' 5. if UID found
    ' 5.1 get data from Sheet1
    ' 5.2 GoTo Sheet 2
    ' 5.3 Past data in right cells
    ' 5.4 GoTo Sheet 1
    ' 5.5 Put check flag in proccessed field
' 6. if UID NOT found
    ' 6.1 GoTo Sheet 2
    ' 6.2 Put delete flag in delete field
' Loop End
'
' GoTo Sheet1
' Search for all parts with no checked process flag
' Copy datasets
' GoTo Sheet2
' Add data to the end of table
---------------------------------------------------
Dim dict As Object
Dim proc As Range
Dim del As Range
Dim chk, myrange As Range
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MetadataSheet")
    
    Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PlanningData")

    ' Read values from sheet2 to dictionary
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Store value to dictionary
        dict(Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 1
    Next

    ' Read from sheet1 and check if each value exists
    lastRow = sheet1.Cells(sheet1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Check if value exists in dictionary
        If dict.exists(sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
            ' found
            sheet1.Range("B2:D2").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheet2.Select
            Sheet2.Range("A2:C2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            sheet1.Select
            sheet1.Range("E2").Select
            Set proc = sheet1.Range("E2")
            proc.Value = "X"
        Else
            ' not found
            Sheet2.Select
            Set del = Sheet2.Range("D2")
            del.Value = "X"
        End If
    Next
'for initial load
sheet1.Select
Set chk = sheet1.Range("E2", "E" & lastRow)
For Each chk In myrange
        If chk.Value = "" Then
            chk.Range("B2:D2").Select
            Selection.Copy Destination:= _
    Sheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2, 1)
              
        End If
    Next chk
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you debug the code? (Go through it, step for step). Do you get any errors? I think `dict(Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 1` might be a culprit. Also, try to avoid selecting things, it is prone to errors.

Comment: It gives an run time error 1004. at sheet1.Range("B2:D2").Select
            Selection.Copy

Comment: Anybody... please!! guide me through

Answer (score 0):

This code is almost working good. For the first run it loads the data from sheet1 to sheet2.
During second run I get an type mismatch error!

```html
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow1, lastRow2, lastrow3 As Long
Dim proc As Range
Dim del As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Metadatasheet")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("PlanningData")

y = 2 'this is the first row where your data will output
x = 2 'this is the first row where you want to check for data
lastRow1 = ws1.Range("B:B").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lastRow2 = ws2.Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

If Not IsEmpty(ws2.Range("B2").Value) Then

    Do Until ws1.Range("B2") = ""
        
        For x = 2 To lastRow2
            If ws1.Range("B2", "B" & lastRow1).Value = ws2.Range("A2", "A" & lastRow2).Value Then
                ws2.Range("A" & y).Value = ws1.Range("B" & x).Value
                ws2.Range("B" & y).Value = ws1.Range("C" & x).Value
                ws2.Range("C" & y).Value = ws1.Range("D" & x).Value
                            
                Set proc = ws1.Range("E" & y)
                proc.Value = "X"
            y = y + 1
            Else
            Set del = ws2.Range("D" & y)
            del.Value = "X"
            End If
        Next x
    Loop

Else
'lastrow3 = ws1.Range("E:E").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For x = 2 To lastRow1
        If Not ws1.Range("E" & y).Value = "X" Then
                ws2.Range("A" & y).Value = ws1.Range("B" & x).Value
                ws2.Range("B" & y).Value = ws1.Range("C" & x).Value
                ws2.Range("C" & y).Value = ws1.Range("D" & x).Value
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next x
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Type mismatch error at   If ws1.Range("B2", "B" & lastRow1).Value = ws2.Range("A2", "A" & lastRow2).Value Then